# Retrofit2 with Query parameter that doesn't work

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have the following json response with some books.

```
[
 {
"title" : "Clean Code",
"author" : "Robert Martin",
"bookUrl" : "http://amzn.to/1DJybxH",
"imageUrl" : "http://adavis.github.io/adept-android/images/clean_code.jpg",
"displayDate" : "August 11, 2008",
"numberOfPages" : 464
},

{
"title" : "Effective Java",
"author" : "Joshua Bloch",
"bookUrl" : "http://amzn.to/1Ku8Xel",
"imageUrl" : "http://adavis.github.io/adept-  
 android/images/effective_java.jpg",
"displayDate" : "May 28, 2008",
"numberOfPages" : 346
},

{
"title" : "Working Effectively with Legacy Code",
"author" : "Michael Feathers",
"bookUrl" : "http://amzn.to/1Jqe1PA",
"imageUrl" : "http://adavis.github.io/adept-android/images/legacy_code.jpg",
"displayDate" : "October 2, 2004",
"numberOfPages" : 456
},

{
"title" : "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code",
"author" : "Martin Fowler",
"bookUrl" : "http://amzn.to/1Lx4cjR",
"imageUrl" : "http://adavis.github.io/adept-android/images/refactoring.jpg",
"displayDate" : "July 8, 1999",
"numberOfPages" : 464
},

{
"title" : "Test Driven Development: By Example",
"author" : "Kent Beck",
"imageUrl" : "http://adavis.github.io/adept-android/images/tdd.jpg",
"displayDate" : "November 18, 2002",
"numberOfPages" : 240
}
]
```

Now I want to performe a seach query and display only those objects whose title contains the word Code ie Working Effectively with Legacy Code and so one. So this is what I am doing.

```
public interface BookService {

  @GET("photos/sample_data")
  Call<List<Book>> getBooks();

  @GET("photos/sample_data")
  Call<List<Book>> search( @Query( "q" ) String query );
```

}

The first @GET request reads all json data. So that part part is working. Now the second @GET request refers to my search method. And as you can see,it contains a query parameter.

Next I call the enqueue(...) method in my Presesenter class(I use MVP). So

```
public class BooksPresenter {
private final BooksContract.View booksView;
private final BookService service;

public BooksPresenter(BooksContract.View booksView,BookService service){
    this.booksView = booksView;
    this.service = service;
}

public void initDataSet(){
    service.search("Code").enqueue(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Book>> call, Response<List<Book>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                booksView.showBooks(response.body());
                Timber.i( "Books data was loaded from API." );

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Book>> call, Throwable t) {
            booksView.showErrorMessage();
            Timber.e( t, "Unable to load the books data from API." );
        }
    });
   }
}
```

This line searches for the word Code.

```
service.search("Code")...
```

However,I still get the whole books,and the query doesn't work. :(. Any ideas?

My whole URL is

```
http://www.theo-android.co.uk/photos/sample_data
```

and I declare the first bit of it in a separate class.

```
public class Constants {
  public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.theo-android.co.uk/";
}
```

Thanks,

Theo.

**UPDATE**

I decided to create a database and add data statically! Next I wrote a php script to produce the json.

```
<?php 
 include("init.php");
 $string="";
 $newString="";
 $get_posts = "select * from books_table";

$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts); 

 $posts_array = array();

 while ($posts_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){


               $row_array['title'] = $posts_row['title'];
               $row_array['author'] = $posts_row['author'];
               $row_array['bookUrl'] = $posts_row['bookUrl'];
               $row_array['imageUrl'] = $posts_row['imageUrl'];
               $row_array['displayDate'] = $posts_row['displayDate'];
               $row_array['numberOfPages'] = $posts_row['numberOfPages'];

               array_push($posts_array,$row_array);

 }

   $string = json_encode($posts_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   echo $string;
 ?>
```

I changed the url to

```
http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample_data.php
```

I get the json back,as showed at the beggining. But with this url

```
 www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample_data.php/q=clean
```

is still have the same problem. So i thought to test my script,and added where clause.

```
<?php 
 include("init.php");
$string="";
$newString="";
$get_posts = "select * from books_table where title='Clean Code' ";

$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts); 

 $posts_array = array();

 while ($posts_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){


               $row_array['title'] = $posts_row['title'];
               $row_array['author'] = $posts_row['author'];
               $row_array['bookUrl'] = $posts_row['bookUrl'];
               $row_array['imageUrl'] = $posts_row['imageUrl'];
               $row_array['displayDate'] = $posts_row['displayDate'];
               $row_array['numberOfPages'] = $posts_row['numberOfPages'];

               array_push($posts_array,$row_array);

  }

   $string = json_encode($posts_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   echo $string;
 ?>
```

and guess what. I still get the whole json response!!!

Comment: out of curiosity, why you named the endpoint `photos` when it is returning books? I tried to query your endpoint from the browser and I am getting the same results. Either you are querying the wrong endpoint or your backend doesn't work

Comment: @Blackbelt It was an old folder in my server. I will change it. But this url  theo-android.co.uk/photos/sample_data/q=code still shows the whole json.

Comment: the issue is backend side. It is not retrofit

Comment: So that's a problem with your backend, not Retrofit query.

Comment: check with POSTMAN it is working or not .....

Comment: @Blackbelt oh boy. How can I fix that? I didn't use any CMS. I just copied the response as it was in on my server. The new ulr is http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample/q=code  still doesn't work. you could try it:(

Comment: Post the file from your server that is used to create the response..

Comment: @rhari. I don't have any php code that performs a query and generates a json. All I have is a folder called books. And inside that folder a file called sample. This file contains the json. And hence the url is theo-android.co.uk/books/sample

Comment: In that case you will have to write a script that performs your query. Or you can search the response that you get on the client side.

Comment: Maybe the file should be have an exception as php. That's a wild guess. ie  theo-android.co.uk/books/sample.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@GET("books/sample/")
  Call<List<Book>> search( @Query( "q" ) String query );
```

instead this

```
@GET("photos/sample_data")
  Call<List<Book>> search( @Query( "q" ) String query );
```

**Note:-you mention this URL in comment is differnt to you using in @Get method ... http://www.theo-android.co.uk/books/sample/q=code**

Comment: I already tried this,but doesn't work. I am still getting all json object back:(

Comment: What do you mean is stopped?

Comment: it means the server have some problem when the URL hit to the server , it close  the server and server not opening again ..... **URL is NOT WORKING** ....

Comment: I see. Maybe I should give the server provider a call

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code for request in initDataSet.

```
List<Book> bookList = service.search("Code");
```

Maybe this code can help you.